# Cannot change directory in Terminal if target has spaces in it

Tags: terminal, bash

I plugged my external HD, then in a Terminal, I type

```
ls /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
```

This lists files and folders as expected, but then entering:

```
cd /Volumes/TOSHIBA\ EXT
```

throws the following message

```
-bash: cd: /Volumes/TOSHIBA\: No such file or directory
```

I can even reproduce this behavior with my own folders.

What is going on here?
How do I change to a directory when it has spaces?

this is my environment context

```
uname -vsr
Darwin 17.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar 5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

Comment: Please [edit your post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/323947/edit) with the output of the command `ls -la /Volumes`

Comment: Try dropping the backslash and just cd /Volumes/TOSHIBA see if that works.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls -la /Volumes` and `ls -laB /Volumes` by editing the question and pasting the result. Also, does `cd /Volumes/TOS*` work?

Answer (score 5):

Spaces in file names can be a hassle in the shell. Your best solution would be to both wrap the name in `"` characters and use the shell's built in completion to get the right name.

Type `cd "/Volumes/TOSH` then type a <kbd>tab</kbd> and the shell will complete the name with any spaces and non-standard characters included. If the <kbd>tab</kbd> completes the entire path then the shell will even insert a `"/` at the end so you are ready to then hit return.

Note that standard `bash` completion will work on file paths and names for most shell commands, not just `cd`.

Comment: Hi, thx for the replay. Unfortunately, this didn't work for me.

Comment: As mentioned by @patrix in a comment on the question, please add the output of `ls -la /Volumes` and `ls -laB /Volumes`.

Answer (score 0):

Guided by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1319472/cannot-change-to-directory-with-space-character-in-it#1319472) response I found that GVM2 "Golang Version Manager" added CD function in my PATH, which somehow took precedence over the BASH CD.